Laravel keep logging user out the first time, the second time user login it will run normally
Previously my website is already working normally but for some reason we need to re-import the file with clean file (backup) and after that this problem keep happening, what have i done is :

change the session type from file to database
clear all data cache data in storage
Restarting apache server
php artisan also
Check the cloudflare but it use DNS so it's not cloudflare problem
not using any load balancer
also checking server firewall and they say it's working normally
changing cookie name
triple check that lifetime is still 120

i also already check laravel.log but there's nothing
i'm using Laravel 7.4
can someone tell me what's wrong with this? it work normally before we use backup file, oh i'm using AWS

okay never mind the second time user login it will work normally but before 120 minute (around 5-10 min maybe less) user will got kicked to login page again
